# How to set text inside a div using JavaScript and CSS

Tags: text, hover

I have issues replacing text with pre defined text when the user hovers over the original text. I have it working on some but not on others. Can someone explain to me what is that I am doing wrong?

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.